# Automatically web scraping button event in python

Tags: python, web, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

How to auto click the load more button on the webpage to get the data during webscraping in python 3?

Comment: What lib are you using, what have you tried so far, what have gone wrong?
You gotta try something and post specific code questions here.

Comment: url = "https://www.inshorts.com/en/ajax/more_news"
    request = requests.post(url, data={'news_offset' : min_news_id})
    print(request.text)

Comment: this is the libary im using ..if anyone can help me load the webpage using load button event it wud be very grateful <div id="load-more-btn" onclick="loadMoreNews()" class="clickable unselectable load-more z-depth-1 hoverable">Load More</div>

Comment: @Alef, you can/should include that into your question.